# How do I export a table or multiple tables from Hbase shell to a text format?

Tags: hadoop, export, hbase, bigdata

I have a table in my Hbase shell with huge amounts of data and I would like to export it to a text format onto a local file system. could anyone suggest me how to do it.

I would also like to know if I could export the Hbase table onto hive or pig.

Comment: echo "scan 'test',{COLUMNS=>'family:col01'}" | hbase shell | grep "^ " > test.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried Hbase export http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/ops_mgt.html which will dump contents of Hbase table to HDFS from there you can use Pig and Hive to access it , I haven't tried this myself ... but appears to address your issue from the documentation .

Comment: Actually I don't see any 'Hive' or 'pig' examples or codes were mentioned on the web page you pointed to.

Comment: The link is HBase documentation, you have to check PIG/HIVE documentation on how you can read the sequence file exported.